# How do I successfully add a menu to my Android app connected to Main Activity?

Tags: android

I wrote code to connect a menu with my Main activity in Android Studio using Java. However, I'm facing an issue where the menu is not visible in the emulator. I need some help to troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

I defined the menu in an XML file, which includes items such as "Settings," "Exit," "Save," and "Cut." Each item has its own ID and attributes. In my Main activity's Java file, I correctly implemented the onCreateOptionsMenu method to inflate the menu XML file and display it in the activity's toolbar or action bar.

Despite my efforts, when I run the application on the emulator, the menu is not displayed as expected. I haven't encountered any specific error messages or warnings so far. It would be great if someone could assist me in figuring out what's causing this issue.

If you have any experience or insights that might help me resolve this problem, please let me know. Additionally, if you need more information about my setup, such as the version of Android Studio or emulator settings, feel free to ask. I appreciate any assistance you can provide in making the menu visible in the emulator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="Settings"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_settings_24"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    <item android:title="Exit"
          android:id="@+id/exit"
          android:icon="@drawable/baseline_exit_to_app_24"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    <item android:title="Save"
          android:id="@+id/save"
        />
    <item android:title="Cut"
          android:id="@+id/cut"
        />
</menu>
```

```
package com.example.lesson77;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settings){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.cut){
            Toast.makeText(this, "CUT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit){
            Toast.makeText(this, "EXIT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.save){
            Toast.makeText(this, "SAVE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxiK3.jpg)
```

I want to add menu. How can I do that?